# The security database on the server does not have a computer / workstation trust relationship - on a domain controller

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2019

"The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship"

This is the message I am getting when I try to log into the only domain controller we have on the network. I have seen this before on workstations and have successfully repaired the trust relationship by unplugging the ethernet cable, logging into the workstation, reconnecting the ethernet cable, leaving and rejoining the domain. I tried unplugging the ethernet cable from the domain controller and logging in as it worked with workstations previously but had no success.

As this is the only domain controller we have, I am locked out of the DC. One positive is that I do have command line and shell access where I can run commands to attempt to repair the error.

Is there a way I can repair this error and gain access to the domain controller to "save the domain"?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

reboot into DSRM and check event viewer for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this wasn't an option because I wasn't onsite!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I was able to edit and remove some aliases within the registry. Specifically "LanManServer".

After removing additional aliases, I successfully logged into the domain controller!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).